# Order being ignored in Sequelize subquery

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following query in Sequelize:

```
UserAccount.findAll({
        attributes: ['user_id'],
        limit,
        offset,
        where: {
            system_usage_email_set: true,
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: Account,
                as: 'account',
                attributes: ['account_id', 'name'],
                required: true,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Site,
                        as: 'sites',
                        attributes: ['site_id', 'domain'],
                        required: true,
                        where: {
                            is_active: true,
                        },
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: Version,
                                as: 'versions',
                                required: false,
                                attributes: ['version_id', 'version', 'status', 'note', 'updated_at', 'config'],
                                order: [['updated_at', 'DESC']],
                                where: {
                                    status: {
                                        [Op.in]: ['SUCCESS'],
                                    },
                                    updated_at: {
                                        [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate],
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    });
```

As you see, I have `order` set on the included `Version` subquery and I want the versions to be ordered by `updated_at` in descending order. For some reason, this ordering is being completely ignored. It doesn't matter if I set the direction to `ASC` or `DESC`, I'm getting the same order regardless. Even if I use a non-existent column name like this

```
order: [['made_up_col_name', 'DESC']],
```

It doesn't even throw an error. In fact, even setting just a random string as the value of order here makes no difference. So it seems no matter what I do the given order has no effect on the returned data. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, very shortly after posting this question I realized what I was missing. Ordering within `include` subqueries is only supported if the `separate` option is set to `true`. So with the subquery looking like this:

```
include: [
    {
        model: Version,
        as: 'versions',
        required: false,
        attributes: ['version_id', 'version', 'status', 'note', 'updated_at', 'config'],
        order: [['updated_at', 'DESC']],
        separate: true,
        where: {
            status: {
                [Op.in]: ['SUCCESS'],
            },
            updated_at: {
                [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate],
            },
        },
    },
],
```

The ordering is now working as expected.